# Return something as well as the FALSE

Tags: php

I am building a library and I want to know If there is a possibility and how the best approach could be done here: Basically I would want to have some different messages that I could display depending on the result in the class.

Psuedo:

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    //query

    if (password hash is verified)

        if (active == false)
            (some sort of MESSAGE HERE! like "User is not activate...")
            return false

        if banned
            some sort of message
            return false
    else

        message (wrong username or password)
        return false
}

And then on the login

if (login(username, password))
    successfully
    redirect
else
    display the message
```

How is the way to implement this in a good approach? I assume I would need some sort of variable that I would give a value and then I would have some method()  that would return a error message if it is set, Am I right so far? How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Global variable (C like)

If you were programming in a statically typed language you would probably use a global variable for the error message (which pollutes your global namespace):

```
global $login_error_message;

function login($user, $password)
{
  if(success)
   return true;
  if(failure)
  {
    global $login_error_message;
    $login_error_message = 'Error message';
    return false;
  }
}

if(login($user, $password))
  redirect
else
{
   global $error_message
   echo $error_message;
}
```

### Member variable (C++ like)

This is logically the same as the global variable but does not suffer from the pollution problem:

```
class LoginClass
{
   private $error_message;

   function login($user, $password)
   {
      if(success)
         return true;
      if(failure)
      {
         $this->error_message = "Error message";
         return false;
      }
   }

   function get_error_message()
   {
      return $this->error_message;
   }
}

$loginInstance = new LoginClass();
if($loginInstance->login($user, $password))
   redirect
else
   echo $loginInstance->get_error_message();
```

### Passing by reference (C/++ like)

Use an additional parameter that is passed by reference to return the error code (which adds extra complexity to the function call):

```
function login($user, $password, &$error_msg)
{
   if(success)
     return true;
   if(fail)
   {
     $error_msg = 'Error message';
     return false;
   }
}

$error_message
if(login($user, $password, $error_message))
   redirect
else
   echo $error_message;
```

### Mixed return type

But since this is php (so not statically typed) you could do the following:

Return true on success (which I suppose needs no special output) and else you return the error message. When using the function you du something like:

```
function login($user, $passord)
{
   if(success)
     return true;
   if(failure)
     return "Error message";
 }

$login_result = login($user, $password);
if($login_result === true)//note the ===, as == would be true on non empty strings too
  success
else
  echo $login_result;
```

### Returning associative array

Of course you could also return an array that can contain both values:

```
function login($user, $password)
{
  if(success)
     return array("success" => true, "error_msg" => "");
  if(failure);
     return array("success" => false, "error_msg" => "Error message");
}

$login_result = login($user, $password);
if($login_result['success'])
  redirect
else
  echo $login_result['error_message'];
```

### Returning class instance (C/++ like)

Likewise you could use a structure like this:

```
class LoginReturn
{
  public $success;
  public $error_message;

  LoginReturn($success, $error_mesage)
  {
     $this->success = $success;
     $this->error_message = $error_message;
  }
};

function login$user, $password)
{
   if(success)
     return new LoginReturn(true, "");
   if(failure)
     return new LoginReturn(false, "Error message");
}

$login_result = login($user, $password);
if($login_result->success)
  redirect
else
  echo $login_result->error_message;
```

### Conclusion

Given these examples I think one can see the advantages and drawbacks of them. Personally I would go with the Member variable variant, as it offers space for more functions that use the same error message infrastructure just by putting them into the class.

Comment: The second example with a boolean return value and ref parameter is surely the most solid option. Global variables will sooner or later cause problems, and the mixing of result types (bool and string) is seen often in PHP, but is as often used wrong. Every developer has to know then, that he must test with `===`, all other methods will be unreliable.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I think likewise, still I am also oriented to get the minimum of code at the end with maximum readability. The most important thing is, that the caller knows the scheme in which error handling is made available here.

Comment: Thanks for a great post, Is there any disadvantages with the Returning class instance method? I thought it was the nicest implementation.

Comment: Well the class instance obviously needs some code to create the class. And as you can see it prevents you from using the login function directly in the `if()` clause (probably using some magic functions one could make this possible). I also looked at the link you gave in one of your other comments. I think there is a class structure used, that internally works like the global variable method (but using a class member instead of a global variable which does not pollute your global namespace)

Comment: @John - That's a good method too (i wrote my comment before this method was there). You could even write the `login()` as a method of this class, a login is worth an own class, i think.

Comment: @John I added another example (Member variable) that should reflect the structure in the site you linked.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Ideally I would want to have the Login() method in the Auth class, else it would probably be no point of having the class itself. I liked the way of return new class due to the structure and look.

If there is no "real" disadvandtage of doing it, I'd love to use that method, unless Im told not to.

Comment: Both the latter new class and member variable is both a good solution, I think, but I am not sure whetever which one I should choose.

Comment: @John If you already have an auth class that should take the login method, then you should include it there. You still could use the class instance returning, but I think that this looks not so clean then (but this is only my opinion).

Comment: So now the question is simply based on what the coder himself think what is most awesome to use, and rather not some sort of problem talkinga bout the performance nor disadvantages?

Comment: @John: I would go for the member variable since it provides for more functions (you could use the same mechanism with logout, change_password and so on by just putting them in the same class), which will then have a unified interface and gives you a cleaner look.

Comment: @John - It's a bit a matter of opinion, but i would **not** use the _Global variable_ and the _Mixed return type_ method, because they can lead to unstable code, if other developers don't pay enough attention. Agree with Nobody about the _Member variable_ method.

Comment: Well good time put on this question, helping me, and taking your time. It's very appreciated, I think many others will have need of this answer in the future. I will vote the answer as "OK". :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In **some languages** (e.g. Python, where structuring program flow by exception handling is well optimized and generally accepted) you could make your login return no value but throw relevant exceptions with a descriptive error code.

Then pseudo-code wise you could do:

```
try
{
    login(user, password);
    redirect(page);
}
catch (MyLoginException ex)
{
    displayMessage();
}
catch (GenericException ex)
{
    ...
}
```

This only holds true for some languages though. This is not advisable for C or C++ for example, where exception handling is really slow thus should be reserved for handling `unexcepted` situations. **PHP** looks to be pretty much in the same boat.

So, since you want to return *two* values (a boolean and a string) the logical course of action is to simply return a `compound` LoginResult object with a boolean and string field.

Return a new instance of a LoginResult object from your login method, and use it's fields to handle redirection and / or displaying an error message.

Comment: Hm looks like python I think you mean `catch`.

Comment: It's better than use return false|true

Comment: Isn't exceptions more for when something "not suppose to happen?" - kind of situation? Like this SHOULD not happen, as if the pdo statement would not be executed? This is rather a user issue, like, the username entered correct username and password but the user is not active, give a false (the user will not get logged in) and then have some sort of message like "The user isn't actually activated", or am I out biking?

Comment: @John, add Catch(Exception $e) and have get $e->getMessage()

Comment: @Sergey What? It was not a problem with the question itself it was a question about using exceptions in thi situation, but I guess everyone does Indeed think I should.

Comment: @John: you may have a valid point, since how `structuring program flow with exception handling` is viewed may differ per language used. In Python for example it's well optimized and well accepted, in C it's historically slow (due to specific implementation issues) and frowned upon. Returning a `LoginResult` object yields the same result without using the exception handling mechanism though.

Comment: @ChristopheD I see I guess that would be some part of the question - I have just been told that exceptions should be used when something "unexpected" is happening, and not as port of some error handling like you know OBVIOUS error handling that would occour quite often (user not activated) I was hoping to see some kind of implementation like http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/ If you take a look at errors() and messages() - But I'm not quite sure its an accurate way of doing stuff, and really don't know how to impelement it, I never looked deep in the library itself.

Comment: I agree with jhon. Putting try - catch block is like over killing.

Comment: @John, itachi: you have raised valid points, I've edited my answer with a little more information.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only to illustrate my comment to Nobody's answer, so give credit to Nobody instead. You could write a class just for login, that can hold the error message.

```
class CLogin
{
  public $error_message;

  function login($user, $password)
  {
    if (successfull)
      return true;
    else
    {
      $this->error_message = $error_message;
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

Or you could simply pass a parameter by reference for the error message.

**Edit:**

Because i believe it is so important [not to use mixed-typed return values](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#mixedReturnType), i wrote an article about the pitfalls of such functions.

Comment: @Corbin - Sorry my mistake, of course i didn't mean this to be a constructor.